# I am using .pac configuration.Gradle is unable to connect to internet even after i select Auto Detect proxy?

Tags: gradle, android-studio

I am using .pac configuration.Gradle is unable to connect to internet even after i select Auto Detect proxy?

How do i set .pac settings to gradle?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem solved. (It worked, but maybe isn't the thing you want)
Here is my way:

1. Visit the *.pac Site in your browser
2. For every entry add an `systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=*.nonproxyrepos.com|localhost` into your gradle.properties
3. Take the return of the IP and the Port and put it into an `systemProp.http.proxyHost=www.somehost.org
   systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080`
4. Maybe you need to include your login information `systemProp.http.proxyUser=userid
   systemProp.http.proxyPassword=password`
5. Rerun

If that don't work try to change the proxy settings of the IDE

http://www.gradle.org/docs/0.8/userguide/tutorial_this_and_that.html#sec:accessing_the_web_via_a_proxy

Hope that helps